# How to add new kernel modules to extension files in Tiny Core Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, tiny-core-linux

I am running **Tiny Core Linux** (TCL) and have installed new **kernel modules** to `/lib/modules/<VERSION>/extra/`. To have those modules available after a reboot, I need to add them to the **extension files**. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   tce-load -wi squashfs-tools
   ```
2. Create a temporary folder:

   ```
   mkdir my-modules
   ```
3. Reconstruct the path to the modules in this folder, the content of this folder is going to be copied to `/` at boot:

   ```
   mkdir -p my-modules/lib/modules/<VERSION>/
   ```
4. Copy the modules folder into this sub-folder:

   ```
   cp -r /lib/modules/<VERSION>/extra my-modules/lib/modules/<VERSION>/
   ```
5. Create an extension:

   ```
   mksquashfs my-modules/ my-modules.tcz
   ```
6. Install the extension:

   ```
   sudo cp my-modules.tcz /mnt/<sda1-or-so>/tce/optional/
   ```
7. Add `my-modules.tcz` to the `/mnt/<sda1-or-so>/tce/onboot.lst` file.
8. Reboot

Comment: 2-4 you may do using normal `make -C $KERNEL_SRC INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/path/to/my-modules modules_install` And you may mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @0andriy I don't want all modules, only my new ones.